# Компланарность векторов не выполняется в наклонной плоскости

Tags: c++, opengl

Пишу свой 3D редактор и столкнулся с проблемой. Мне нужно выделить весь внешний контур, в котором лежит только что созданный мною внутренний контур, ну а потом выполнить триангуляцию...

Алгоримт примерно таков:

1. Взять любые три точки внутреннего контура, которые не лежат на одной прямой, и сформировать 2 вектора.
2. Далее итеративно пробежать по всем точкам в пространстве, формируя 3 вектор
3. Проверить 3 вектора на компланарность. Если да - то точка лежит в плоскости моего внутреннего контура.
4. Потом выполнить convex hull для всех точек, лежащих в плоскости моего внутреннего контура.
5. Соединяем и получаем внешний контур.

Работает только для плоскостей xOy, yOz, xOz. То есть только если внешний контур находится в этой плоскости, смешанное произведение векторов равно 0. Если выполнить те же действия в наклонной плоскости, то смешанное произведение будет равно в пределах [-0.005; 0.005]. Подозреваю, что существует некая погрешность, (тип данных float) но не знаю как решить эту проблему.

P.S. Перепробовал еще несколько способов, но ничего не получается и кажется это самый правильный способ.

Comment: *"Подозреваю, ..."* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1):

Смешанное произведение даёт объём параллелепипеда, построенного на этих трёх векторах. Если дело в погрешности (возможны и другие варианты, кода ведь мы не видели), то можно сравнивать полученное значение, разделённое на произведение длин векторов (сравнение с объёмом прямоугольного параллелепипеда), с неким малым допуском.

```
if (abs(mixedProduct) < lenA*lenB*lenC*1E-6)
```

Можно также искать длину проекции точки на плоскость (расстояние до плоскости).

Comment: попробовал с допуском и расстояние от точки до плоскости -  тот же самый результат

Comment: в общем-то есть продвижки некоторые, но все очень как-то рандомно, то находятся эти точки(при том не все), но нет. (под разным углом камеры)
для того, чтобы построить контур, я использую _ray-plane intersection_ может быть проблема в том, что точки пересечения с наклонной плоскостью находятся неточно? от того и весь сыр-бор

Comment: Да, точка пересечения луча под малым углом к плоскости определяется с большой погрешностью. А что значит - тот же самый результат?

Comment: В том смысле, что определяет те же самые точки, что и при проверке на компланарность.

Comment: Сделали проекцию точки P на плоскость, померили длину PP'. Мала по сравнению  с порогом? Используем далее проекцию P', а не  P.

Comment: С погрешностями при малых углах пересечения (в т.ч. на плоскости) дело тяжёлое. Вон Шевчук специальную арифметику придумал ради [триангуляции](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html)